# OutOfMemoryError issue in Vertex buffer Object (VBO)

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, vbo

I'm facing problem here when moving from VAO to VBO for rendering. I'm using Android platform and using OpenGL API from JNI.
Here is my snippet code

```
// Initialize in constructor
GLuint buffer[3];
glGenBuffers(3, buffer);

// In onDrawFrame(), I create draw function.
// My object data will be dynamically updated during runtime so I used GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW.

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, genData.cubeNumVerts * 4, genData.vertex, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, genData.cubeColorVerts *4, genData.colors, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[2]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, genData.cubeNormalVerts * 4, genData.normals, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);


  if(genData.vertex == 0 || genData.normals == 0 || genData.colors == 0) LOG("Error: failed to allocate a memory");


  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[0]);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
  glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,0);

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[2]);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
  glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,0);

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[1]);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);
  glVertexAttribPointer(mColorHandle, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,0);

  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, genData.cubeNumVerts);

  glDeleteBuffers(3, buffer);
```

by using this snippet code, I got OutofMemoryError when rendering. I could not figure out what might cause this error. if anyone notice the inapproriate of using VBO from this snippet code please help me.

Thanks

Comment: There is no need to recreate your buffer each time. Reuse them.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I just put it at initialization (see comment line that I said I put it in constructor). Do you see other mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer size specified in `glBufferData` is the size of the data in **bytes**. So you say each buffer is `numVerts * 4` bytes large (and I hope all those `cube...Verts` numbers are all equal, otherwise that's just bound for errors and confusion), but then you tell `glVertexAttribPointer` that you got `numVerts * 3` (or `numVerts * 4` respectively) 32-bit floats, and thus `numVerts * 3 (or 4) * 4` bytes of vertex data. So `glDrawArrays` will read over the actual data, likely resulting in some access violation or other undefined or erroneous behavior.

Comment: Hi, 

all the cube verts numbers are equal. but I could not understand your explanation here

" and thus numVerts * 3 (or 4) * 4 bytes of vertex data. So glDrawArrays will read over the actual data, likely resulting in some access violation or other undefined or erroneous behavior."

can you explain more clearly?

thanks

Comment: @deduu With your `glBufferData` call you copy `numVerts*4` bytes into the buffer. Then when calling `glVertexAttribPointer`, you say that a vertex position consists of 3 floats and thus `3*4 = 12` bytes. When you then draw `numVerts` vertices with `glDrawArrays`, it tries to read `numVerts*3*4` bytes from a buffer that only contains `numVerts*4` bytes.